# New row is not added in component

Tags: angularjs

Here I am using angular Tree for component. When the data is entering first time it is working fine.

But the data is coming from backend, then the adding row button is not adding.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)
Here is my code.

```
$scope.newSubItem = function(scope) {

        var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
        nodeData.items.push({
            id: nodeData.items.length?(nodeData.items[nodeData.items.length-1].id)+1:nodeData.id * 10,
                    rowId: nodeData.rowId + '.' + ((nodeData.items.length?(parseInt(nodeData.items[nodeData.items.length-1].rowId.split('.').pop()))+1:1)),
                    items: []
        });
    };
```

The error is

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at Scope.$scope.newSubItem (app.js:19)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12332)
    at callback (angular.js:22949)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14383)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14482)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:22954)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3011)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when a node has no child elements you are not returning empty array in items from the server

[image]

Either add code on server side which adds an empty array in items

or

@Sajeetharan is right you need to add this code in your newSubItem function

```
$scope.newSubItem = function(scope) {

    var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
    if(!nodeData.items)
        nodeData.items =[];
    nodeData.items.push({
        id: nodeData.items.length?(nodeData.items[nodeData.items.length-1].id)+1:nodeData.id * 10,
                rowId: nodeData.rowId + '.' + ((nodeData.items.length?(parseInt(nodeData.items[nodeData.items.length-1].rowId.split('.').pop()))+1:1)),
                items: []
    });
};
```

Comment: how you were able to reproduce the debug window? :O

Answer (score 2):

Before pushing you need to initialize the array if its null,

```
nodeData.items = [];

$scope.newSubItem = function(scope) {
   var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
   if(nodeData && nodeData.items ){

   }        
};
```

Comment: condition on nodeData will have no effect, he has to check nodeData.items for null